# Ошибка вывода результата при вводе пароля

Tags: c, строки

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
char **input_pass;
scanf("%s", &input_pass);

if (input_pass == "123")
{
    return printf("Equals");
}
else
{
    return printf("You made mistake");
}

}
```

Никак не пойму почему выходит ошибка. Если ввожу 123 выводит "You made mistake". Если ввожу что-то другое выводит "You made mistake" и ошибку: [image: Скриншот ошибки]

Всем спасибо. Вот как решил проблему:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
char **input_pass; char main_pass[] = "123";
scanf("%s", &input_pass);

if (strcmp(&input_pass, &main_pass)==0)
{
return printf("Equals");
}
else
{
return printf("You made mistake");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Ваши советы очень помогли!

Comment: нет, проблема не решена совсем. Во-первых, ваш код вообще не собирается. Но даже если получится его скомпилировать - введённые данные по-прежнему засаживаются в произвольную область памяти. То, что код работает в одном случае - не значит ровно ничего, в другом случае он отформатирует винчестер, предварительно опубликовав  все ваши логины/пароли на публичном ресурсе.

Comment: Ваш комментарий ценен для меня. Хотел бы вас попросить предоставить больше информации где я бы смог найти больше информации об этой проблеме. Как сделать так чтоб введённые данные не засаживались в произвольную область памяти?

Comment: Для начала - в любом учебнике/руководстве по языку C для начинающих. Можно создать новый вопрос с "итоговым" кодом, так как к первоначальному вопросу он уже отношения не имеет и разводить ликбез тут в комментариях - не дело.

Comment: Новий вопрос задал здесь [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574709/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В чем собственно дело?

Вот в этом:

```
if (input_pass == "123")
```

Вы сравниваете два адреса в памяти (указателя), которые заведомо не равны. Для сравнения строк в C используются функции семейства [strcmp()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=3&russian=&topic=strcmp).

Ну и до кучи: у вас полный бардак с памятью и указателями. В функцию `scanf` вы передаёте непонятно что, ввод идёт в произвольное место памяти...

Answer (score 2):

Строки нужно сравнить через функцию `strcmp`. Сравнивая через `==` Вы сравниваете адреса, а не сами строки. При этом даже одинаковые строковые литералы не обязаны располагаться по одинаковым адресам, т.е. вполне вероятна ситуация, когда `"abc" == "abc"` даст ложь.