# Как сделать так, чтобы вводимые данные не попадали в произвольную область памяти?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **input_pass;
    char main_pass[] = "qwerty123";
    scanf( "%s", &input_pass );

    if( strcmp( &input_pass, &main_pass ) == 0 ) {
        return printf( "Equals" );
    }
    else {
        return printf( "You made mistake" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Хотя этот код и компилируется, введённые данные попадают в произвольную область памяти. Какие здесь ошибки и как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Может все-таки хватит просто указателя при объявлении `input_pass`?

Comment: Почитайте в документации, какой тип аргумента ожидает `%s`. Посмотрите, что у вас. Сделайте выводы. Повторите то же для функции `strcmp`. Прочитайте предупреждения, которые вам выдал компилятор при компиляции этого.

Comment: Указатель `input_pass` указывает неизвестно куда. Почему бы Вам (для начала) не читать пароль просто в символьный массив? Напишите `char input_pass[100];` и попробуйте.

Comment: Выходит, что ошибка была вот здесь `char **input_pass;` Спасибо вам огромное! Я обязательно возьму ваши советы во внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принцип работы со строками в C в том, что они представляют собой массив символов (`char`), последним, ограничивающим элементом которого является нулевой символ `\0`. А переменная-строка по сути является указателем на первый элемент этого массива. Еще одно соображение - что имя массива можно рассматривать как (константный) указатель на его первый символ.

Исходя из этого, рассмотрим, что же надо функции `scanf("%s",???)`. А нужно ей указать место в памяти, куда считывать данные. Т.е. по сути адрес места, где будет располагаться первый считанный символ.

Вспомним сказанное ранее. Если у нас есть массив, то его имя и есть этот адрес, так что можно написать

```
char array[50];
...
scanf("%s",array);
```

Память можно выделить динамически, например:

```
char * str = malloc(50);
...
scanf("%s",str);
```

После первой инструкции `str` указывает на выделенную память (т.е. содержит адрес первого символа в этой памяти).

Точно такие же аргументы хочет и функция сравнения строк `strcmp` - указатели на первые символы строк. Так что, как и в `scanf`, в `strcmp` нужно передавать указатели *на место в памяти*, где хранятся строки (а не на место в памяти, где хранятся адреса первых элементов), т.е.

```
strcmp(sr, array);
```

Comment: При отладке вывило: Программа "[3848] InputToSystem.exe" завершилась с кодом 6 (0x6).

Comment: @Владимир Дайте полный код программы - что ж можно сказать без кода?...

Answer (score 3):

При вводе строк в массив типа char следует всегда давать размер поля ввода меньше длины массива, чтобы избежать выхода за его границы, учитывая что в конец ещё запишется нуль. Передавать в scanf при этом нужно адрес первого элемента массива:

```
char buf[50];
scanf("%49s", buf);
```

**Никогда не используйте `%s` без указания длины.**

Согласно POSIX.1-2008 можно так же использовать модификатор `m`, чтобы `scanf()` сама разместила вводимую строку в динамическом массиве, который следует освобождать через `free()`. При этом передать нужно уже адрес указателя на первый элемент массива байт:

```
char *buf;
scanf("%ms", &buf);
```